# VS Code double "zoom in" bug

Tags: visual-studio-code

a weird problem:

VSCode has zoom in and zoom out options. When I want to zoom in, I just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad_Add</kbd>.

If I zoom in two times (which is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad_Add</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad_Add</kbd>) the outside border of the VS Code window shrink just a tiny bit.

So, how do I know that? Whenever I try to close the window from the `"x"` on the upper right, the mouse is not on the `"x"` button. I mean the farthest corner is not occupied by VS Code window.

Maybe it is a bug, or maybe something wrong with my pc.

Need help with this.

Thanks.

Screenshots (the mouse pointer is in the corner):

[image: with only 1 zoom in(mouse is in the corner)]

[image: with 2 times zoom in(mouse is in the corner)]

Comment: Probably would be better to include a before and after screenshot to show what you mean with 'the outside border'.

Comment: screenshots are added

Answer (score 0):

It seems like on Windows zooming in the full UI also zooms the title bar, apparently this is intended for accessibility reasons (even though it doesn't do this on macOS).

If you just want to zoom in the text in the editor (and not the other UI stuff) you can use the font zoom commands: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_font-zoom-commands

Or if you're okay with using the mouse wheel to zoom you can set the setting `editor.mouseWheelZoom` to true, which will allow you to perform a font zoom by holding ctrl and scrolling.

Comment: Just zooming the code is nice. Thanks for the guidance.